# Calculate device aspect ratio with SASS

Tags: sass, node-sass

First of all, using [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio) media query is not an option. It is barely supported by any browser so using it would be not the best idea.

The objective is to calculate device aspect ration and then conditionally apply SASS styles. Ideal (but not working) example:

```
=aspect_ratio_landscape_apply()
  $device_aspect_ratio: calc(100vw / 100vh)
  @if $device_aspect_ratio > 1.8
    @content
```

So it does not work as I can't use anything from CSS in SASS variable definition. I can't use `calc()` in `@if` as well. Is there any sane workaround?

For those curious I'm trying to conditionally add left and right margins (or some other styles) for edge to edge mobile devices in landscape mode. If you have any other approach I would love to look at it as well.

Note that treating edge to edge mobile device in landscape as desktop won't work. Viewport height is not enough to accommodate needed stuff there.

Thanks!

Comment: Sass is a pseudo code compiled into css before getting in to the browser, so sass will never know about browser viewport size. The best approach will be to calculate browser viewport aspect ratio using JavaScript and the apply a class (to the body maybe) to apply the desired styles.

Comment: Sass can't calculate device aspect ratios. (Since Sass compiles into CSS, Sass can't do anything CSS can't do.) Are you trying to restrict the width of content on landscape mobile devices? If so, you might try something like `.content { max-width: 30vmin; }`

Comment: @muecas yeah but apparently CSS can using calc. I thought there might be some magic SASS stuff that would hack it. 

But yeah, seems like there is no such stuff. Really wanted to avoid using JS after all.